# Passing byte array from C# to C++ DLL as char*

Tags: c#, c++, dll, pinvoke, marshalling

I am passing a `byte[]` from C# to C++ DLL

Inside the C++ DLL, I need to call a function which accept and read  `istream` object, I intend to receive the `byte[]` from C# as `char*` and convert it to `istream`,

C++ DLL

```
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) bool CheckData(char* data, int dataLength)
```

C#

```
[DllImport("example.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool CheckData(byte[] incoming, int size);

public void Process(byte[] bytes)
{
    CheckData(bytes, bytes.Length);
}
```

Although it seems to work fine, I find that the equivalent data type of `byte[]`  is `unsigned char*` in C++, I thought of changing to `unsigned char*` but most `stream` in C++ works on `char*` not `unsigned char*`

I would like to ask

1)  Both data type `char*` and `unsigned char*` are 1 byte, what happened behind? Is there any potential problem if I keep using `byte[]` with `char*`?

2) In case there is any problem, how should I use `unsigned char*` to construct an `istream` object?

Comment: It's fine as you have it.

Comment: Do you know what happend behind? I wanted to understand what had happened

Comment: Nothing much happens. There is in effect a reinterp cast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the `char *` and `unsigned char *` type sizes are not 1 byte, but rather 4-bytes, assuming we are talking about a win32 application : those are pointers, and all pointers have the same size regardless of the size of the data being pointed at.

When the P/Invoke mechanism sees an array of "simple values" as a function argument, it happily feeds a pointer to the start of the array to the C function underneath. After all, all it *really* knows about the C function from the info in the DLL is where its code starts. As far as I know, the number and type of arguments is not encoded in the symbol name, so it trusts the info you provided. Which means that even if you'd fed it an `int` array, the actual call to the C function would have worked, as the size of the arguments pushed on the stack (a pointer and an int) match the ABI of the function. Of course the processing would have probably been wrong as the size wouldn't have matched.

See also https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75dwhxf7(v=vs.110).aspx for more details about what happens.

Processing is where the difference between `unsigned char` and `char` comes : if on the C# size you do some math on the `byte` values (ranging 0-255), pass it on the C side where `char` values (-128 to 127) are expected
to do some more math, something could go wrong. If it just uses it as a way to move data around, it's all fine.